# Renaming the name of variable in a list in R

Tags: r, list

Consider I have a list:

```
 >li

 $`first`
 [1] "Hello"

 $test
 [1] 3 4 5
```

I was trying to change the value of 'first' by below command:

```
names(li["first"]) ="sign"
```

But it didn't change the name for the variable. 
Can someone please tell me why didn't it changed or how this code works?

Consider, the list is big. I would like to know how to change the names for variable without indexing.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for that. Do you know why my first command was not working or whats going on there?

Comment: I think @Rui has explained it well in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because when you do `names(li["first"]) = "sign"` what you are doing is:

1. `li["first"]` - Extracting a sublist from the list. This creates a new list.
2. `names(li["first"])` - Getting the names of the sublist, not of the original list.
3. `names(li["first"]) = "sign"` - Assigning the new name `"sign"` to the one member of the sublist. The original list `li` has nothing to do with this, it was lost for the instruction the moment you extracted the sublist. On function `'names<-'` exit, the sublist is lost, the new sublist exists only in the environment of function `'names<-'`.

And this is absolutely general, not just for lists.
If you want to change the `names` attribute of an R object you must get the value of that attribute first and subset the `names`, not the object. When subsetting the object you are creating a new one; when subsetting the attribute you are keeping the object intact.

If you don't know the index number of the list member whose name you want to change, the right way is in @Ronak Shah's comment. And if you want to change many names at the same time, use `%in%` instead of `==`.

```
# Ronak Shah's comment
names(li)[names(li) == "first"] <- "sign"
names(li)
#[1] "sign" "test"

# To change 2 names use `%in%`
li2 <- list(first = "Hello", test = 3:5, second = letters[1:5])
names(li2)[names(li2) %in% c("first", "second")] <- paste("sign", 1:2, sep = "_")
names(li2)
#[1] "sign_1" "test"   "sign_2"
```

**Edit.**

After a comment by user Mikko Marttila I have decided to explain the above more accurately.

> I think this is a good breakdown of the sort of "heuristic" to
>   understand what happens, but it isn't quite accurate to what actually
>   happens. Expanding the replacement functions in `names(li["first"]) = "sign"`
>    ends up being equivalent to doing
>
> ```
> li <- "[<-"(li, "first", value = "names<-"(li["first"], value = "sign"))
> ```
>
> Usually this distinction won't matter, but if e.g. `li["first"]` has a
>   class with a misbehaving `'names<-'()` method you're in for a nasty
>   surprise.

**The wrong way.**
Let's break the instruction in the comment in pieces.
It starts by extracting a sublist from list `li`.

```
sub_li <- `[`(x = li, i = "first")
sub_li
#$`first`
#[1] "Hello"
```

Then it sets a new name to one of this sublist's members (the only one, `"first"`).

```
sub_li <- `names<-`(x = sub_li, value = "sign")
sub_li 
#$`sign`
#[1] "Hello"
```

Then it assigns the value of the sublist `sub_li` to a member of `li`, the member `"first"`.

```
li <- `[<-`(li, "first", value = sub_li)
#li
#$`first`
#[1] "Hello"
#
#$test
#[1] 3 4 5
```

Now, apparently `li` hasn't changed. But it did, the new value is `"Hello"`. It's not R's fault if the old and the new values are equal, R did what it was instructed to do.
To prove that something happened, I will change the value of `sub_li["sign"]` and run the exact same instruction.

```
sub_li["sign"] <- "Goodbye"

li <- `[<-`(li, "first", value = sub_li)
li
#$`first`
#[1] "Goodbye"
#
#$test
#[1] 3 4 5
```

See? R was not buggy. The glitch is that this is not what the programmer intended.

**The right way.**
The right way is much simpler. Start by creating the original list `li`.

```
li <- list(first = c("Hello"), test = c(3, 4, 5))
```

The code that works above (Ronak's code) is `names(li)[names(li) == "first"] <- "sign"`. Forgetting the logical index and using the index number `1`, this breaks down to two instructions.
The first is the assignment `'[<-'(x, i, values)`.

```
stuff <- `[<-`(x = names(li), i = 1, values = "sign")
```

The second is the assignment of new values to attribute `names`.

```
`names<-`(x = li, value = stuff)
#$`sign`
#[1] "Hello"
#
#$test
#[1] 3 4 5
```

The one-liner R executes is

```
li <- `names<-`(x = li, value = `[<-`(x = names(li), i = 1, values = "sign"))

li
#$`sign`
#[1] "Hello"
#
#$test
#[1] 3 4 5
```

That's it.

Comment: (+1) I think this is a good breakdown of the sort of "heuristic" to understand what happens, but it isn't quite accurate to what _actually_ happens. Expanding the replacement functions in `names(li["first"]) ="sign"` ends up being equivalent to doing `li <- "[<-"(li, "first", value = "names<-"(li["first"], value = "sign"))`. Usually this distinction won't matter, but if e.g. `li["first"]` has a class with a misbehaving `"names<-"()` method you're in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I know I simplified what happens but if the OP has some trouble understanding it, maybe it's better like this. I will edit the answer with a more accurate explanation, borrowing from your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I think it was a good answer, and certainly easier to grasp the idea that way! I was mostly commenting "for the sake of completeness." If you do include some of it in the answer, I think it should definitely be labelled as the "in depth/advanced" explanation

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```
li <- list(first = c("Hello"), test = c(3, 4, 5))
```

We can directly call out the first element in the list by a [1] and rename it with "sign" (which is what you require).

```
names(li)[1] <- "sign"
```